How to update state without Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded
//API
  const {
    data: jobsData,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetJobsQuery(curCustomers.map((item) => item.id).join(","));

  const [activeFilters, setActiveFilters] = useState({});
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(jobsData?.data);

//filter data functional
  const filterFields = ["customer", "work_zone", "status", "employee"];
  useEffect(() => {
    if (jobsData?.data) {
      const filtered = filterData(jobsData.data, activeFilters, filterFields);
      setFilteredData(filtered);
    }
  }, [jobsData, activeFilters]);

  //sort data functional
  const sortFields = [
    { name: "number", sortBy: "date" },
    { name: "execution_date", sortBy: "date" },
    { name: "auction_end", sortBy: "date" },
    { name: "auction_start", sortBy: "date" },
  ];
  useEffect(() => {
    if (filteredData) {
      const sortedData = sortData(filteredData, activeFilters, sortFields);
      setFilteredData(sortedData);
    }
  }, [filteredData]);

Can't figure out how to update filteredData state without warning.
I get jobsData from API. First useEffect listening changes and when data coming, call filterData func to make filtering. Also i need use sortData func to make sorting my state filteredData, so some how i need to change  filteredData state, next i render my data with filteredData.

One of your effects is called when the filteredData state changes but it also changes the filtered data state which leads to an infinite loop.

Yeah, thats's true, but i need listening filteredData changes, to sort this state and render actual data. That's the problem  - how to keep filteredData actual?

I recommend that filteredData should not be a state at all. It can be entirely calculated from other values during rendering. In addition to getting rid of the rendering loop problem you have, it will get rid of extra renders entirely. It also makes it so the filtered data is never out of sync with the jobs data, not even briefly (the useEffect version has one render that's out of sync, then it sets state to put the states back in sync)
const {
  data: jobsData,
  isLoading,
  isError,
  error,
} = useGetJobsQuery(curCustomers.map((item) => item.id).join(","));

const [activeFilters, setActiveFilters] = useState({});
const filteredData = useMemo(() => {
  if (!jobsData) {
    return undefined;
  }

  const filterFields = ["customer", "work_zone", "status", "employee"];
  const filtered = filterData(jobsData.data, activeFilters, filterFields);
  const sortFields = [
    { name: "number", sortBy: "date" },
    { name: "execution_date", sortBy: "date" },
    { name: "auction_end", sortBy: "date" },
    { name: "auction_start", sortBy: "date" },
  ];
  const sortedData = sortData(filtered, activeFilters, sortFields);
  return sortedData;
}, [jobsData, activeFilters]);


Wow, great, thanks, it's works, the only thing - first arg sholud be "filtered" in sortData func
